# How I can parallelize a 'for' loop with an external variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, pywikibot

I am having difficulties parallelizing that part of code where `new_text` is of type unicode:

```
for old, new in self.replacements:
    line = pywikibot.replaceExcept(
        line, old, new, self.excsInside, self.site)
if new_text != entry.text:
    yield pywikibot.Page(self.site, entry.title)
```

The task looks to be easy with [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) or a [process-pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), but there is `new_text` which is used outside of the loop. I have no idea of the equivalent of`#pragama omp ordered`or`#pragma omp atomic`, since there is no OpenMP wrapper for [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)...

How do I determine what the value of new_next is going to be in the `if` statement if it's run in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

As it is inherently sequential, you can parallelize per line:

```
for line in new_text
    for old, new in self.replacements:
        line = pywikibot.replaceExcept(
            line, old, new, self.excsInside, self.site)
```

Ánd you parallelize the outer `for` loop (map with each replacement and then reduce by concatenation).

Comment: I tried your code serially *(just pasted it inside replace.py)*... The program run during hours without any result, whereas it take 40min to finish normally.